# find session state for all users in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session

I use VS2010, C# to develop ASP.NET web app, I create some sessions in my app, is there any way that I can know about sessions of all users? I think this should be possible since sessions are created by server code, I want to know session states of all users, for instance I want to know how many online users I have at each moment (by looking at session["userid"]), is there any way around that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not possible to access the session of all other users. You are
>   allowed to access you own session object not others.

But you can implement it using Application object and other methods.

Ref: [Getting number of active sessions (online users counter) with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/stoianbucovich/archive/2009/06/26/getting-number-of-active-sessions-online-users-counter-with-asp-net.aspx)

Handle the Application events in global.asax file:

```
//When application start first time set onilne user to 0
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Application("OnlineUsers") = 0

End Sub

Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Application.Lock()
Application("OnlineUsers") = CInt(Application("OnlineUsers")) + 1

Application.UnLock()

End Sub

Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Application.Lock()
Application("OnlineUsers") = CInt(Application("OnlineUsers")) - 1

Application.UnLock()

End Sub
```

Other Implementation methods reference:
[Getting online users](http://forums.asp.net/t/1384953.aspx)
[ASP.NET Membership – Show list of users online](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/07/13/ASPNET-Membership-Show-list-of-users-online.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you **cant** access the session of all other user except your own.

you also have a Session

what you can do is write some data into the `Application` Object or to the `Cache` Object.

that way  - you can access it from each request - no matter who is the user.

Comment: oh thanks, would you please give some guidance about Application object or Cache object? how can I work with them?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access sessions I strongly recommend using Session State Mode as SQLServer.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx
you can then access the sqlServer tables where all session are stored very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can access all session state from everywhere simply create a Collection of HttpSessionState and save it into the application state... When a session is started add it to the collection

example: `Application("SessionCollection").Add(Session)`

So you can access any session state (you could implement session lookup functions to simplify your task)

You could implement a timer inside your collection that would check all session state and remove dead ones

It works on every version of ASP.Net